# Pulling external changes using bitbucket

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

I've created a Mercurial repository using import of another repository on code.google.com (It is not mine).

I want to sometimes pull changes from source repo to mine.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pull the changes into your local clone:

```
$ hg pull https://code.google.com/...
```

and then you push them to Bitbucket:

```
$ hg push https://bitbucket.org/...
```

There is no built-in way to make Bitbucket do the pull on their side, you have to ferry the changesets from the external repository into the one on Bitbucket.

If you want to do that more than one time you may create names for this repositories. To do that edit `.hg/hgrc` in repository directory to be like following:

```
[paths]
google = https://code.google.come/..
bitbucket = https://bitbucket...
```

After that you may use original command a bit nicer:

```
$ hg pull google
$ hg push bitbucket
```